# Checking for nil model using reactive cocoa?

Tags: reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I was wondering what the approach for checking for nil values with reactive cocoa is.

I would assume I could create a signal like so.

```
// Turn state check into a signal to activate the rest
RACSignal* modelSignal = [self checkIfModelIsValid:self.model];

[[modelSignal then:^RACSignal *{
        return [self obtainImageSignal];
        // Always need to lazy call these functions
    }]
    subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        NSLog(@"It worked out! giving you null for fun though feel free to chain it? %@",x);
    }
    error:^(NSError *error) {
        // Replace with real ns error
        NSLog(@"Model or picture is nil: %@",error);
    } 
    completed:^{
        NSLog(@"Model this event started it all");
    }];

-(RACSignal *)obtainImageSignal {
    @weakify(self)
    RACSignal* imageSignal = [[NetworkManager sharedInstance] getImageWithImagePath:self.model.fullSizedPicture];

    // Processes that image signal
    [[imageSignal deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]
         subscribeNext:^(UIImage* image) {
             @strongify(self)
             self.imageView.image = image;
             [self setUpTitle:self.model.title];
             [self setUpDescription:self.model.imageDescription];
         }
         error:^(NSError* error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);
         }
         completed:^{
             NSLog(@"Completed Operation: Image Retrieval Operation");
         }];

    return imageSignal;
}


-(RACSignal *) checkIfModelIsValid:(PhotoModel*) model {
    // Using then on this signal will force the image signal to handle the errors.?
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {

        if (self.model == nil || self.model.fullSizedPicture == nil) {
            [subscriber sendError:nil];
        }
        else {
            [subscriber sendNext:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
            // send complete for fun and see what it does
        }

        return nil;
    }];
}
```

Or is it the case where sanity checking does not apply to react functional programming ?

Comment: I am not really sure if I question is clear. Do you want to check if `obtainImageSignal` returns nil?

Comment: You are right the question is a matter of style or preference I should just mark it like so.

Comment: But why ignore:nil, filter or map doesn't t work for you then?

Comment: Yeah I should have used map it would work for ignoring nil thank you!

Comment: [Operations like](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/BasicOperators.md#filtering) `filter` can help you in this case where you want to ignore  nil values

Comment: If you need more help, I can post an answer with a more detailed example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give an example for other viewers, a way to make sure that you're not fetching any images from a model that is `nil` - one could do something like:

```
    RAC(self.someImageView, image) = [[RACObserve(self, model)
        filter:^BOOL(PhotoModel *currentModel) {
            return currentModel != nil;
        }]
        map:^id(PhotoModel *currentModel) {
            return [self someMethodToDownloadImageFromModel:currentModel];
        }];
```

Notice how I try to avoid using `self` inside my RAC blocks and avoid injecting side effects which occurs when using `subscribeNext:^`, `then:^`etc. This way your code gets easier to manage and more RAC.

Comment: Isn't this what the `ignore` method is for? `[signal ignore:nil]`

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely do that @DougMcBride